# React native, pod install doesn't install subspecs

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

RN tutorial github project looks like this,
[image]

whereas mine only has `Core`

[image]

I tried `rm -rf Pods && rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"` and `pod install`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the subspecs installed from a fresh swift project by following the React Native guide https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html with a pod file like this:

```
target 'testpods' do
  # Your 'node_modules' directory is probably in the root of your project,
  # but if not, adjust the `:path` accordingly
  pod 'React', :path => './node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'DevSupport', # Include this to enable In-App Devmenu if RN >= 0.43
    'RCTText',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTWebSocket', # needed for debugging
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
  ]
  # Explicitly include Yoga if you are using RN >= 0.42.0
  pod "Yoga", :path => "./node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"
end
```